# Spring Boot + TestNG + MockMVC gives Null for @Autowired

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, testng, mockmvc

I'm new to Spring-Boot, TestNG and MockMVC, when i try to write TestNG test case it gives Null for below:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
```

and also it gives null for

```
@BeforeTest
public void start()
{
     mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}
```

Also, based on previous post from stackoverflow by moving

`mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();` to **@Test** also the problem not resolved.

Below my code snippet

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void testEmployee() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/employee")).andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("emp1")).andExpect(jsonPath("$.designation").value("manager"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.empId").value("1")).andExpect(jsonPath("$.salary").value(3000));
}
```

Any link or working sample shared will be great help.

thanks

Comment: Can you include more code? (e.g. the annotations at the top of the class)

Comment: @TwiN i have added the code Snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to autowire `WebApplicationContext`, your test class should be annotated with `@ContextConfiguration` and `@WebAppConfiguration`.

You can find an example-ish [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/context/testng/web/TestNGSpringContextWebTests.java) (Spring Framework's official repository).